# remove image that show with glob() with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, glob

how can i give an increment specific id to div.pix-box like pix-1 , pix-2 ,...
in order to remove them with ajax?

```
$images = glob("user/$username/"."*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png}",GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach($images as $image) {
        echo '<div class="pix-box"><img src="'.$image.'" />'.'<br>';
        echo '<form class="remover" action="admin-delete.php" method="post">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$image.'" name="delete_file" />';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete image" />';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

and this is my ajax script:

```
$(".remover").on('submit',(function(d) {
    d.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "admin-delete.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:  new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
          cache: false,
      processData:false,
      success: function(data)
        {
                $('#pix-....').remove();

        },
        error: function() 
        {
        }           
     });
```

and admin-delete.php:

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists('delete_file', $_POST)) {
  $filename = $_POST['delete_file'];
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
    unlink($filename);
    echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
  } else {
    echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your problem. Code working, I suppose.

Comment: code working without ajax and needs to refresh page, for using ajax i suppose i must give an increment id to divs that contain images,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an incremental variable:

```
$i = 1;

foreach($images as $image) {
    ...
    $i++;
}
```

Now you can use `$i` to add a unique suffix to any id you want.